# Entire Function Which Tends to Zero At Infinity In All Directions

Tags: complex-analysis

Say we have an entire function in the complex plane which tends to zero in all directions, i.e.
$$f(z)\to 0 $$ as $$|z|\to \infty $$
Intuitively, this seems highly unlikely to me. There are many functions which would tend to zero in several directions, but I doubt any entire function could in all directions. I am however at an utter loss in trying to prove my intuition. I have no idea where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a theorem that states that a bounded entire function must be constant. (Liouville).

Comment: But bounded everywhere? Because it only tends to zero at infinity? What about small values near the origin for example?

Comment: If it tends to zero at infinity, than there exists a disc, such that outside this disc, the function is $\leq \epsilon$. Inside the disc, it is a continuous function on a compact, and therefore also bounded. Therefore, bounded everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M,R$ be positive constants and $n$ a natural number.

An entire function $f(z)$ satisfying $\|f(z)\|\leq M\|z\|^n$ for all $z$ with $\|z\|\geq R$ is necessarily a polynomial of degree at most $n$. The special case when $n=0$ is called Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: Great! I actually wanted the case n=0 to prove all the other cases. Now I know they are all true. Thank you.